# global controller in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is there a way in codeigniter to define a global function that can be called in all controllers easily?

I have a application that will show all latest users who have registered on the app.

what im doing now is, i have autoloaded a model `Latest_model` with the below function

```
function new_users()
{
  $this->db->select('*');

  $this->db->from('users');
  $this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC'); 
  $this->db->limit('5');

  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result_array();

}
```

and on all the controllers, at the beginning i call this model

```
$data['new'] = $this->Latest_model->new_users();
```

It works but, i need to repeat this in all the functions.

So what would be the best way to achieve this?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: _Suggestion:_ Create a base controller with that method and let your other controllers extend it.

Comment: or go for creation of helper or library..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always extend default controller with new functionality. [Codeigniter's documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html) is the good place to start.

In short you should create your base controller named `MY_Controller` under `application/core/` folder.
Then you can place inside this file some code like this:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    protected $data = [];

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->data['new'] = $this->Latest_model->new_users();
    }
}
```

Then from all your controllers you can access the `data` array with `$this->data`.

Comment: @LiveEn This is great answer, and also in addition you can check [Avenirer's MY_Model](https://github.com/avenirer/CodeIgniter-MY_Model) that can help you to simplify interaction with various models you are using in application.